# nginx rewrite or internal redirection cycle

Tags: nginx

Im banging my head against a table trying to figure out what is causing redirection cycle in my nginx configuration when trying to access URL which does not exist
Configuration goes as follows:

```
server {
        listen       127.0.0.1:8080;
        server_name  .somedomain.com;
    root  /var/www/somedomain.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/somedomain.com-access.nginx.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/somedomain.com-error.nginx.log debug;

        location ~* \.php.$ {
        # Proxy all requests with an URI ending with .php*
        # (includes PHP, PHP3, PHP4, PHP5...)
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        }

        # all other files
        location / {
            root  /var/www/somedomain.com;
        try_files $uri $uri/ ;
        }

    error_page 404 /errors/404.html;
        location /errors/ {
                alias /var/www/errors/;
        }       

        #this loads custom logging configuration which disables favicon error logging
        include /etc/nginx/drop.conf;
}
```

this domain is a simple STATIC HTML site just for some testing purposes.
I'd expect that the error_page directive would kick in in response to PHP-FPM not being able to find given files as I have fastcgi_intercept_errors on; in http block and nave error_page set up, but I'm guessing the request fails even before that somewhere on internal redirects. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the client browser reporting a redirect loop, or is nginx?  If it's the client, what location are the redirects to?

Comment: both are reporting it. Client eventually ends up with the URL of  /errors//errors//errors//errors//errors/...404.html

Comment: What's the log entry from nginx look like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The culprit is: `try_files $uri $uri/ ;`

http://nginx.org/r/try_files (note that the last parameter is return code or URI to internal redirect)

> If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified by the last parameter is made.

Comment: Thanks. Just had one of these errors with a Roots Trellis LEMP setup. Happened after a WooCommerce data import. Never had it before. What would you recommend in these cases? Remove the parameter `$uri/`? See parameter here:https://github.com/roots/trellis/blob/cbe647a26a95126a3cf7fd8ace7f1f2f0454adf0/roles/nginx/templates/wordpress.conf.j2#L9

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, this is the culprit:

```
    try_files $uri $uri/ ;
```

It creates a redirection loop, since the last parameter of `try_files` should point to the location if the file isn't found. I solved it by adding a `=404`, like this:

```
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404 ;
```